# JBOSS Application Server and Servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jboss

I downloaded latest version of Jboss from [JBOSS website](https://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads).

I created a Dynamic Web Project and create a servlet in it. Servlet class has build path errors as shown in image below. I explored server directories and it did not include any servlet jar. How can I get JBOSS server which include servlet and web jars in it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The servlet jar in JBOSS server should be present under:

```
JBOSS_HOME/common/lib/
```

most likely with name `servlet-api.jar`
It should also be included in your class-path.

Comment: Server I downloaded has no folder like common/lib/

Comment: Latest JBoss has no concept of shared common lib. It's all divided in the modules.

Comment: Then why my server is not picking up jars itself to build project?

Answer (score 2):

JBoss has those files, but what it doesn't have is a common classpath folder (common/lib). Everything is divided into separate modules.

This is partly the reason for why if you want to work with Eclipse without Maven (or similar build management tool), you should use JBoss Tools extension. There are full instructions here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Starting+JBoss+AS+from+Eclipse+with+JBoss+Tools

JBoss Tools will configure you

- JBoss runtime, containing references to servlet api + other needed files
- JBoss server that you can use to deploy from Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following dependency to your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>CHOOSE YOUR CORRECT VERSION HERE</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I guess OP is not using Maven.